# JQuery: Clickable Items on top of clickable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a clickable div that opens as you can see here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Sj575/277/

My problem is that when the div's open content that is clickable appears on top of it (kind of like a gridder).
But when I click on the things on top, it does registers the image animation abut the div closes.

JQUERY (div)

```
$(function() {
    $(".ext").click(function() {
        $(".int").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".ext").toggleClass("full");
        $("h1").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".pe").toggleClass("show");
    });

    $(".int").click(function() {
        $(".ext").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".int").toggleClass("full");
        $("h1").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".pi").toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

JQUERY(gridder)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Call Gridder
    $(".gridder").gridderExpander({
        scrollOffset: 60,
        scrollTo: "panel", // "panel" or "listitem"
        animationSpeed: 400,
        animationEasing: "easeInOutExpo",
        onStart: function () {
            console.log("Gridder Inititialized");
        },
        onExpanded: function (object) {
            console.log("Gridder Expanded");
            $(".carousel").carousel();
        },
        onChanged: function (object) {
            console.log("Gridder Changed");
        },
        onClosed: function () {
            console.log("Gridder Closed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If someone has a good answer could you please give it an upvote for other people?

Comment: i already chose the correct awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a click event to only fire on the parent div, and not its descendants, try using the following comparison in your $(".ext") and $(".int") div click handlers:

```
if (e.target !== this)
    return;
```

Working example whereby I've added a child button that won't cause the grow/hide animation on click: http://jsfiddle.net/zxagqwvq/

So you'd have something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".ext").click(function(e) {

    if (e.target !== this)
        return;

    $(".int").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".ext").toggleClass("full");
    $("h1").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".pe").toggleClass("show");

    });

    $(".int").click(function(e) {

        if (e.target !== this)
            return;

        $(".ext").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".int").toggleClass("full");
        $("h1").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".pi").toggleClass("show");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I updated the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what i asked ut it also helped after this tnks fot your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a click-event from going any further, by using this:

```
$(".ext").click(function(event) {
    ...
    event.stopPropagation(); //Event tree stops here. No parent elements will be notified of the event
});
```